# MDX multiple conditions filter on multiple dimensions

Tags: mdx, cube

I am relatively new to MDX, about a month or so, and I am now writing MDX queries against a remote cube I also work on (Java 8 ActivePivot).

This query works when they are ORs, but when I add parentheses and change that first OR to an AND it works, kind of, but drops the measure resulting in the CDR and BOOK dimensions coming back correctly. Can someone with more MDX knowledge tell me what I have missed or do not yet know?

```html
WITH 
Member [Measures].[CDR_Label] AS [CDR].[CDR].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION  
Member [Measures].[Book_Label] AS [Book].[Book].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
  {[Measures].[CDR_Label],
  [Measures].[Book_Label],[Measures].[RepoRate.LATEST]} 
ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
FILTER(
([CDR].CHILDREN,[Book].CHILDREN), (LEFT([CDR].[CDR].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION,1) = "8") AND 
(LEFT([Book].[Book].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION,2) = "ST" OR 
RIGHT([Book].[Book].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION,4) = "CIES")) 
ON ROWS 
FROM [TraderCube] 
WHERE ([Date].[Date].[2019-10-23])
```

[image]

And here the query before I changed it, with OR OR etc which works. I wanted the above to return only the CDR beginning with 8, which it does, but it loses the measure (and also breaks my headers - as this is actually being fired from inside an xll / custom Excel function, to a dll calling the remote cube using AdomdClient package as I am building a very custom plugin - Essentially the ability for users to use simple words/from enumerations presented and I then translate and construct MDX in C# to fire at the cube. Data comes back and I send 2D arrays back to Excel :)).

```html
WITH 
Member [Measures].[CDR_Label] AS [CDR].[CDR].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION  
Member [Measures].[Book_Label] AS [Book].[Book].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[CDR_Label],[Measures].[Book_Label],[Measures].[RepoRate.LATEST]} 
ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
FILTER(
([CDR].CHILDREN,[Book].CHILDREN), 
LEFT([CDR].[CDR].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION,1) = "8" OR 
LEFT([Book].[Book].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION,2) = "ST" OR 
RIGHT([Book].[Book].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION,4) = "CIES") 
ON ROWS 
FROM [TraderCube] 
WHERE ([Date].[Date].[2019-10-23])
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the orignal and the modified query. Plus can you share the results of both.

Comment: OK I edited it, remove the escape chars (as im testing this in C# as described).

Comment: Essentially confused as to why I've changed it to (="8") AND ("ST" OR "CIES") instead of (8 OR ST OR CIES) and it loses the measure! :O

Comment: Oh ignore those to 0 valuers in pic 2, usually there are headers there but I turned them off as they break in the query when it loses the measure...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aah...ignore me!

I think I was tired and didn't see the pattern. Essentially, and I just reproduced this, if you ask for two dimension patterns that do exist with a measure, you get back the dimensions you expect (in my case 3, a real measure and two fake / labels for the dimensions to bring them all back as rows).

If there are no matches it seems to return you back what you asked for without any measures as they do not exist for the dimension combination.

Comment: Yeah I confirmed it. I just asked for a certain CDR with a book from a completely different CDR. [CDR].[CDR].[A] , [Book].[Book].[a book from CDR E] and a measure. I got back 2 columns with one row containing the two things I asked for. I'd have expected no results! At least I know for my header mapping and 2D array dimensions etc.

Comment: I've amended my C# code (as I know the dimensions and measures requested) and I now know that if it does not find the combination asked for, it returns you the dimensions you asked for as axes. Above I asked for 2 dimensions and 1 measure, which would usually result in 3 axes resulting in 3 columns for me, as it talks in axes it just gave me back 2 axes containing the dimensions i asked for. Now control my header row based on requested instead of tupleColumnCount. In my returning 2D Object array the requested combo of dims & measures goes back as a header row regardless of what is found.

Comment: If nothing is found you get the dimensions you asked for and 0 as a result for any measures. If the combination is correct you'll get the dimensions you requested and a value for the measure(s).